# Putting Columns within columns using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap grid system and have run into an issue. I want to make a section of a page that is divided down the center, with separate information on each side. My html looks like this.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="friendly col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <!--stuff goes here-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <!--stuff goes here-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="friendly col-sm-6">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <!--bigger stuff goes here!-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

CSS

.friendly {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The issue that I am having is that in order for the two larger divs to be inline, they have to be made smaller (like one a col-sm-4, and one a col-sm-6) and the col-sm-3s wont take up the whole col-sm-6. How do I put a column within a column properly and have everything be sized correctly? And shouldnt there just be basically 12 sections for me to dice up as I please? is there something that changes if I have a column in a column? Thanks

Comment: You have nested columns without the required row in between. It's not clear what structure you seek.

Comment: Nesting indeed requires a `.row` in between. I'm quite sure you can't set `display: inline-block` on `<div>`'s with bootstrap column classes on them. Are you looking for a layout like `SIDEBAR (3x) | CONTENT (6x) | SIDEBAR (3x)`?

Comment: Indeed, nesting columns without an intervening row layer [is a Bootlint error.](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E014)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're after, but it seems like a much simpler structure would do.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--stuff goes here-->
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--stuff goes here-->
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <!--bigger stuff goes here!-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in a layout like so:

```
| 25% | 25% |     50%     |
```

For what it's worth, here's the same layout with a nested row:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <!--stuff goes here-->
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <!--stuff goes here-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <!--bigger stuff goes here!-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the columns in each row level sum to 12 units.

Comment: Thank you! This cleared up a lot for me. I didn't realize you had to create new rows when nesting. I also didnt realize that, say if you had a row in a "col-sm-6", that column would again be divided up by 12.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example of nested column structures:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/1r1tKKb5Mj)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="well">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="well">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="well">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**

The `well` class is used to show where the elements would be placed, but can be replaced with whatever you would like.

Hopefully this gives some insight.

**Edit** Too many containers, `row` will accomplish the same thing.

Cheers!

Comment: What is the purpose of the inner `.container-fluid` element?

Comment: Hmm. You know, there might not actually be one. **Edit** In this case, there isn't one. I just derped.